A workaround for conditionally calling React hooks
Is it correct to render a component which return null and only has some hooks and logics? (A workaround for conditionally calling React hooks) just for minimizing the amount of imported lines and reduce code complexity
const MainComponent = () => {
  const [hasLogic, setHasLogic] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {/*A workaround for conditionally calling React hooks*/}
      {hasLogic && <LogicComponent />}
    </div>
  );
};


// another file
const LogicComponent = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    /// logics
  }, []);

  /// logics as functions

  return null;
};

I can use custom hooks but it would have lots of imported files and codes in memory... I don't want those unnecessary codes to be downloaded... it can be managed with lots of inline imports but it makes code ugly
======================== my actual problem
const MainComponent = ({hasLogic}) => {
  useMainHook(hasLogic);

  return (
    <div>
      {/*A workaround for conditionally calling React hooks*/}
      {/*Some components*/}
    </div>
  );
};

//another file
//this file could have lots of imports
const useMainHook = hasLogic => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasLogic) {
      // api calls
      // lots of logic
    }
  }, [hasLogic]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (hasLogic) {
      // set some listeners
      // lots of logic
    }

    return () => {
      if (hasLogic) {
        // remove listeners
      }
    };
  }, [hasLogic]);
};

I want to run useMainHook() conditionally cause of its a heavy file with lots of imported functions from other files.
As you know each import will be downloaded on page request. so to prevent downloading useless codes I have two way:
1- use inline import which makes code ugly
2- conditional hook which is not possible in react
What is the best practice to handle this?

Technically yes, but a component that only has side effects sounds like bad design to begin with.

If you can edit the question to show the actual use case, I think you can get a more useful answer.

@jsejcksn It's a huge file with lots of logic (imports and listeners)... I want only they be downloaded when the conditions is true. I updated a question

"Is it correct to render a component which return null and only has some hooks and logics?" - Some may say yes while others may say no. It's subjective, unanswerable, and not on-topic for Stackoverflow. The workaround seems "ok" to me (i.e. it doesn't break any React rules) if that is really what you want to do and it actually solves a problem you have in your code. It kind of sounds like your question is about code-splitting and not specifically about hooks. Can you [edit] to clarify the actual problem you are trying to solve for here? Is this an XY problem?

Sorry, it's still not clear if you are trying to solve a code-splitting problem (e.g. only import what you need when you need it), or a code performance problem (e.g. calling a "heavy"/"expensive" function). I don't think there's much you can do for code-splitting the useMainHook hook from the UI code since it must be called unconditionally. If you need to conditionally call/apply some logic then update useMainHook  to return a function that can be invoked exactly when you want it to be called. Does this make sense?

@DrewReese Yes it's more about code-splitting and prevent some .js files be downloaded in initial request which it's not needed on that time (only if condition is true I need those .js files be downloaded and use). I just know that with inline imports we can achieve this but it makes codes complex.

you can conditionally render a component inside another component. But when you create a custom hook, React JS documentation encourages using custom hooks to share logic between your components. So when you create a hook, you should have something to return and use it in different components.
you can read more about the way of using custom hooks here.

Hi Hamed, still with custom hooks there are a lots of imported files and codes in memory... I don't want those unnecessary codes to be downloaded... I can manage it with lots of inline import but it makes code ugly
